# Finding a finite number of congruent classes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

this is my first question on stackflow :) I made a quick research and many just keeping plugging numbers of $x$. I am looking for a clear strategy or a specific formula to follow:

"Find all integer solutions to the equation $2x^2 \equiv 5x + 1 \pmod{17}.$ Give your answer as a finite number of congruence classes modulo $17.$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying numbers is almost our best way.  The usual trick for solving $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ is to multiply by $4a$ and complete the square, which gives:

$$(2ax+b) \equiv b^2-4ac \pmod{p}.$$

In your congruence we have

$$(4x-5)^2 \equiv 33 \pmod{17}.$$

At this stage, there's not a lot you can do, unless you get lucky.  There is an algorithm called the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm which will grind out square roots modulo a prime, but it's complicated.  In this case, you do get lucky, because $33\equiv 16 = 4^2 \pmod{17}$ and because $17$ is prime.  So you have $4x-5\equiv \pm 4 \pmod{17}$.  You can solve both those congrences for $x$ in the usual way, and get the only two solutions.

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$17$ is prime so $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ is a field.

and $2x^2-5x-1\equiv 2(x+3)^2-2 \pmod{17}$